# Regex find the string between last two quotes " "?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

For example, this is my string -> `abcd 1234abcda="author 1" content="author 2.">\n`

I only want the string `author 2.` by using the function `str_extract()` in R. How can I use regex to do that? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
string = 'abcd 1234abcda="author 1" content="author 2.">\n'
sub('.*"(.*)".*', '\\1', string)
#[1] "author 2."
```

With `str_match`

```
library(stringr)
str_match(string, '.*"(.*)"')[, 2]
```

---

Another option is to extract all the values with "author" followed by a number and select the last one using `tail`.

```
tail(str_extract_all(string, 'author \\d+')[[1]], 1)
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit about why sub('.*"(.*)".*', '\\1', string) will not select the "author 1"?  The regex looks like anything"anything"anything to me, so I don't know why the "author 1" won't be selected. Thank you.

Comment: That is because regex are by default greedy meaning it will try to capture as many characters as possible before returning a match. In case, you wanted to return "author 1" as output you could make the regex non-greedy which can be done by using `?`. So `sub('.*?"(.*?)".*', '\\1', string)` will give "author 1".